# Strange load of XML

Tags: php, xml, dom, base64, serialization

I don't know why this generated xml: [here](http://bvsreal.cz/foto.xml) appears from the first load (only for few seconds) as text, and after like xml. Problem is that I want to send it via cURL. I thought that problem was in generating XML with DOM, so I tried XML_Serializer from PEAR, but the result is the same.

Another reason is I thought it could be generating Base64_encode(image) but if I save this file from browser and try to push only this file in testing mode, it says that's ok. And if I try to put this file (stored with browser) to web folder (upload via FTP) and display in browser, it displays normally. (no with 1-2 sec. as code from start).

I have really a headache from this. So I will be pleased for any thing that I need to do. 
Thank you for a reply.

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();

$property_id = $_GET['u'];

function resizeImage($image,$width,$height,$scale) {
    list($imagewidth, $imageheight, $imageType) = getimagesize($image);
    $imageType = image_type_to_mime_type($imageType);
    $newImageWidth = ceil($width * $scale);
    $newImageHeight = ceil($height * $scale);
    $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newImageWidth,$newImageHeight);
    switch($imageType) {
        case "image/gif":
            $source=imagecreatefromgif($image); 
            break;
        case "image/pjpeg":
        case "image/jpeg":
        case "image/jpg":
            $source=imagecreatefromjpeg($image); 
            break;
        case "image/png":
        case "image/x-png":
            $source=imagecreatefrompng($image); 
            break;
    }
    imagecopyresampled($newImage,$source,0,0,0,0,$newImageWidth,$newImageHeight,$width,$height);

    switch($imageType) {
        case "image/gif":
            imagegif($newImage,$image); 
            break;
        case "image/pjpeg":
        case "image/jpeg":
        case "image/jpg":
            imagejpeg($newImage,$image,90); 
            break;
        case "image/png":
        case "image/x-png":
            imagepng($newImage,$image);  
            break;
    }

    chmod($image, 0777);
    return $image;
}





//xml reader
function xml2assoc($xml) {
    $arr = array();
    if (!preg_match_all('|\<\s*?(\w+).*?\>(.*)\<\/\s*\\1.*?\>|s', $xml, $m)) return $xml;
    if (is_array($m[1]))
        for ($i = 0;$i < sizeof($m[1]); $i++) $arr[$m[1][$i]] = xml2assoc($m[2][$i]);
    else $arr[$m[1]] = xml2assoc($m[2]);

    return $arr;
}

//na obrazky
function encodeme($encodeMe) { 
    $data = base64_encode($encodeMe); 
    $datalb = ""; 
    while (strlen($data) > 64) { 
        $datalb .= substr($data, 0, 64) . "\n"; 
        $data = substr($data,64); 
    } 
    $datalb .= $data; 
    return $datalb; 
} 

// cURL
function get_web_page( $url,$curl_data ) 
{ 
    $options = array( 
        CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE => 25000,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,         // return web page 
        CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,        // don't return headers 
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,         // follow redirects 
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",           // handle all encodings 
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "bvsreal",     // who am i 
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,         // set referer on redirect 
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 12000,          // timeout on connect 
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 12000,          // timeout on response 
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,           // stop after 10 redirects 
        CURLOPT_POST            => true,            // i am sending post data 
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $curl_data,    // this are my post vars 
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,            // don't verify ssl 
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,        // 
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => 1                // 
    ); 

    $ch      = curl_init($url); 
    curl_setopt_array($ch,$options); 
    $content = curl_exec($ch); 
    $err     = curl_errno($ch); 
    $errmsg  = curl_error($ch) ; 
    $header  = curl_getinfo($ch); 
    curl_close($ch); 

  //  $header['errno']   = $err; 
  //  $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg; 
    $header['content'] = xml2assoc($content); 
    return $header; 
} 




//co bude inzerat zac (I - insert, U - update, D - delete)
$typ_operace = $_GET['typ_operace'];
if(!$typ_operace) $typ_operace = 'I'; // defaultně vkládání



//vytvoření nemovitost.xml dokumentu
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
$dom->formatOutput = true; 
$autorizace = $dom->createElement('autorizace');

$username = $dom->createElement('username', 'xxx');
$autorizace-> appendChild($username);

$password = $dom->createElement('password', 'xxx');
$autorizace-> appendChild($password);

$software = $dom->createElement('software', 'xxx');
$autorizace-> appendChild($software);

$unikatni_id_rk = $dom->createElement('unikatni_id_rk', $property_id);
$autorizace-> appendChild($unikatni_id_rk);

$data = $dom->createElement("rows");


    $sql_foto = "SELECT * FROM rl_images WHERE property_id = '$property_id' ORDER BY ord LIMIT 25";
    $query_foto = mysql_query($sql_foto);
    while($foto = mysql_fetch_array($query_foto)){
        $row = $dom->createElement('row');
        $data-> appendChild($row);

        $typ_operace =  $dom->createElement("typ_operace", 'I');
        $row->  appendChild($typ_operace);

        $foto_unikatni_id_rk = $dom->createElement('foto_unikatni_id_rk', $foto['image_id']);
        $row-> appendChild($foto_unikatni_id_rk);
        //zde bude foto_data v base643

        $imgfile = '../rl_images/'.$foto['src'];

    $img = file_get_contents($imgfile);
    //$encoded = strtr(base64_encode(addslashes(gzcompress(serialize($img),9))), '+/=', '-_,');
    if($img)$encoded = base64_encode($img);
    $foto_data = $dom->createElement('foto_data', $encoded);
    $row-> appendChild($foto_data);

        // pokud je vyplněn popis, dám ho tam, pokud ne dam tam poradi
        if($foto['description'])$popis = $foto['description'];
        else $popis = $foto['ord'];

        $foto_popis = $dom->createElement('foto_popis', $popis);
        $row-> appendChild($foto_popis);

        if($foto['ord']=='1')$hlavni = 1;
        else $hlavni = 0;
        $foto_hlavni = $dom->createElement('foto_hlavni', $hlavni);
        $row-> appendChild($foto_hlavni);

        $foto_poradi = $dom->createElement('foto_poradi', $foto['ord']);
        $row-> appendChild($foto_poradi);


    }



    //$rk_id = $dom->createElement('unikatni_id_rk', $property_id);
    //$data-> appendChild($rk_id);
    //$clanek->setAttribute("autor", false);

    //$stat = $dom->createElement('stat', '263');
    //$data-> appendChild($stat);


$autorizace-> appendChild($data);

$dom->      appendChild($autorizace);


$dom->      save("foto.xml");



//vložení nemovitosti
$curl_data = array(
                    'data'=>'@foto.xml',
                    'software'=>'software'
                    );

$url = 'http://www.urbium.cz/import/foto.php';
//$cwd = getcwd();
$response = get_web_page($url,$curl_data); 
  //chdir($cwd);
print '<pre>'; 
print_r($response);
print '</pre>';




ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Response is:

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://www.urbium.cz/import/foto.php
    [content_type] => text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-2
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 420
    [request_size] => 253
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.082448
    [namelookup_time] => 0.001688
    [connect_time] => 0.005283
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.005408
    [size_upload] => 428104
    [size_download] => 134
    [speed_download] => 1625
    [speed_upload] => 5192412
    [download_content_length] => 134
    [upload_content_length] => 428104
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.009477
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [content] => Array
        (
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [status] => OK
                    [cesta] => 
                    [file_out_velka] => 
                    [sql_hf] => 
                )

        )

)
```

cesta means source
velka means big

Comment: It appears as text because it is being loaded. It takes around 1.5s to load that small XML in my location. While it is not loaded browser can't display it as document is not complete. Second time it is loaded fast because it is taken from cache. Completely not clear to me what is wrong with that image file - I just do not understand your question

Comment: Ok, so that's i dont know why this file if is stored(in my pc) and put it via tested mode -> via form is ok and will passed. But if i try to put this file via cURL, logging and another will be ok but another server did not recognize the photo data, from file posted via cURL.

Comment: So, you are taking that XML and post it with cURL to another server. But it does not recognize images inside that file. At the same time beign posted to that second server with a form - image data is recognized and handled correctly, right? If so - show your code.

Comment: Have you checked what is returned in response? As far as I can see from docs at urbium.cz they should return XML with error description. And possibly it will be better to contact urbium team to get help

Comment: Ofc. response is now posted. I contact them but still without response... so i try find some bugs on my side. But still without any solutions.